# How to write binary ArcGRIDs outside of ArcGIS in linux?

Tags: raster, geoprocessing, gdal

I've been looking for a way to create\write binary formatted ArcGRID images in Linux without much luck.  It seems the GDAL project only supports reading these files, but there is not write support.  My major problem with this is that I have raster images being created in custom C++ programs and I'm using ArcGIS Server to display them.

Most operations in ArcGIS Server regarding raster processing via geoprocessing services seems to require the data to be in the binary ArcGRID format (or automatically converts to this format).  Converting from another format to the ArcGRID format on the ArcGIS Server is just too slow for web apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that the binary ArcGRID format is proprietary and undocumented. An easy solution would be to write your data out as an open standard (e.g. GeoTiff) and use MapServer (or other WMS) to display it.